# UITableView with Dragging

Tags: ios, ios5

I have an iPad application with UITableView, and I want to enable a user to reorder the table items by dragging the cell and move it before or after another cell, how I can do that ?

Tanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` method in your data shource to update the model on the end of the drag operation. Implement `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` to return `YES` for the rows that the user should be able to move.  [Here](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/) is a short tutorial on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement these dataSource methods in your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    //update your model to reflect the fact that the specified rows indexes have been swapped
}
```